# SharePoint 2013: Retreving the list of files on a List I always get an empty result

Tags: 2013, rest, provider-hosted-app, sharepoint-on-prem

I have a list in SharePoint on Premise in which I know there are 2 files and a folder. If I try to get the list of files from it I always get an empty response like in the example:

`GET :url/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/Documents')/Files`

```
{
  "d": {
    "results": []
  }
}
```

I know from a call to `GET :url/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/Documents')/Properties` that the list has 3 items (the 2 files and a folder) but neither the files nor the folders appear when I call through the REST interface (they appear on the web though).

Any idea on where to start debugging this?

If I repeat the same call from the browser after authenticating as a user I get a response with the files/folders I expect.

EDIT:

More details, The app is a provider hosted high-trust app. I use a JWT token to authenticate the user (through active directory) generated as explained here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn762439.aspx

EDIT2:

`url:` is `https://spop-domain.com/_api`

EDIT3:

I've tried different users to make sure it was not the user I was tryint. I've also tried creating a new application in SharePoint and using a new certificate to sign the tokens. None of those did work. I'm still getting an empty list of results on `/Files`, `/Folders` and `/Items` while the list details sais that `ItemCount` is 3 (2 files and a folder).

Comment: Are the files actually located in the library that has the folder address `/Documents` ? Your code works fine for me (provided I sub `url/web/...` with `/_api/web`). It's possible that the library name and its URL are quite different.

Comment: Yes, they do, sorry, forgot to comment that :url is in fact `domain/_api` however, I know for sure that the files are there and the api can return them because I can get them by making a get just from the browser once I'm authenticated on the on-premise server.

Comment: If you go to a webpage on your host web and do a Javascript request in your browser dev tools like `$.getJSON("/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('/Documents')/Files", function(data) { console.log(data) })` does it have any data in the results?

Comment: Then I get the results I am expecting (the 2 files).

Comment: You might be accessing the documents folder in your app web. Make sure it is the host web that you access. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nickpinheiro/archive/2015/01/30/build-a-sharepoint-hosted-app-to-access-list-data-in-your-host-web-using-the-rest-api-in-10-easy-steps.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link. I already had a look into it, but my app is a ruby on rails backend app, I'm doing all the calls from the ruby code, no javascript involved. I'm sure that the host is the right one since I can get the info with the same call from the browser instead of the ruby code. The only difference is that the ruby code authenticates through a token while calling from the browser uses the existing cookie from sharepoint. Oh, and tons of thanks both @John-M and you for your replies :)

Comment: Have you checked if the app is properly authenticated and can do post requests to SharePoint? Is there a bearer authorization header in the request? Also check fiddler for any kind of message.

Comment: I have the similar cases:
If I ran the REST call with 

"www.example.com/_api/web/getFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/<subsite>/documents')/files"
It returned 0 count.

However,
"www.example.com/_api/<subsite>/web/getFolderByServerRelativeUrl('documents')/files"
It returned correct count.

Is that your cases?

Comment: This scenario comes up only when i hit the `/Files` api only when there are folders at the document library and vice versa. But you are sure that you tried both right? Also i believe there is no `/Items` api.